# Excel COM in C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2012, com, worksheet

So I am working in visual studio 2013 and I am trying to return the string in a given cell in a worksheet.

```
    public StringBuilder MyCellData(int rCnt, int cCnt)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Excel.Range range;

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("");

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\james.naughton\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\QA_Automation\QA_Automation\copyChangeReportWAccountID.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "Landeck1", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets.get_Item(1);


        range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange[rCnt,cCnt];
        str.Append((range.Item[rCnt, cCnt]).ToString());

   return str;
```

Now whenever I run the program for some reason the values for range and xlWorkSheet are always COM Object, so when it is not returning what I want it to. Any suggestions on how to access the correct worksheet and return the data from a cell?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the Value of your cell:

```
str.Append((range.Item[rCnt, cCnt]).Value.ToString());
```